# Calling python method from java

Tags: java, python, jython

I have Python class:

```
import smtplib

class em():
    def greet(self):
        to = 'ant.......nov@ya..dex.ru'
        gmail_user = 'ant0.....ov@r..mbler.ru'
        gmail_pwd = 'Y2V.........fHdZ'
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.ramer.ru",587)
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        smtpserver.starttls()
        smtpserver.ehlo
        smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
        print (header)
        msg = header + '\n this is test msg from  \n\n'
        smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
        print ('done!')
        smtpserver.close()

a = em()
a.greet()
```

And I have Java method:

```
public void $doIt() throws PyException {
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\CODING\\GIT\\arNote\\src\\main\\java\\com\\antonromanov\\arnote\\email\\python')\nimport sende");
        interp.exec("print sys");
        interp.exec("print sys.path\n" + "print" );
...
```

I want to pass some parametres from java to python method and call them, but I recieve:

```
org.python.core.PyException: null
    ...
    at com.antonromanov.arnote.email.python.Testp.$doIt(Testp.java:52)
```

String number 52 is:

```
    interp.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('C:\\CODING\\GIT\\arNote\\src\\main\\java\\com\\antonromanov\\arnote\\email\\python')\nimport sende");
```

with my code. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3? I assume from ` interp.exec("print sys");` you are using python2 correct?

Comment: @ Error - Syntactical Remorse - my version is 3,7

Comment: Then the that will through an error. `print` in python3 requires parenthesis. Make sure all code you are running is valid python 3 code in a python IDE before running it with java.

Comment: if comment string #52 with interp.exec("import sys\nsys.path.a.... bla bla bla - all works good!